# Comparing list of dictionaries when the keys are out of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, equality

I have 2 lists of dictionaries.

```
a = [{"name": "hello", "city": "xyz"},{"city": "rty", "name": "ert"}]
b = [{"city": "xyz","name": "hello"},{"name": "ert", "city": "rty"}]
```

The above two lists are equal. But if I make a comparison using `==`, it gives `False`. How could I check for equality between two lists of dictionaries when the keys could be out of order?

Comment: I get `True` for `a == b`... Used Python 3.6.3

Comment: which python version are you using, please specify

Comment: maybe you men that the dict elemnts may not be on the same positions in the lists?

Comment: @kederrac yes...

Comment: @Amanda if this is the case you may have a look over my answer

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you made a mistake somehow. I and others get `True`:

```
>>> a = [{"name": "hello", "city": "xyz"},{"city": "rty", "name": "ert"}]
>>> b = [{"city": "xyz","name": "hello"},{"name": "ert", "city": "rty"}]
>>> a == b
True
```

And that's what it *should* do.

The documentation about [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) says (emphasis mine):

> **Equality tests** between `OrderedDict` objects and other `Mapping` objects are **order-insensitive like regular dictionaries**.

And the documentation about [Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) says this, which is the case for those dicts:

> Mappings (instances of `dict`) compare equal if and only if they have equal *(key, value)* pairs.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to know if each list has the same dicts even the dict elements may not be on the same positions in the lists (as you mention un the comments) you can use:

```
a = [{"name": "hello", "city": "xyz"},{"city": "rty", "name": "ert"}]
b = [{"name": "ert", "city": "rty"}, {"city": "xyz","name": "hello"}]

print(a == b)
print(sorted(a, key=lambda d: sorted(d.items())) == sorted(b, key=lambda d: sorted(d.items())))
```

output:

```
False
True
```